# Should an adult around 40 like me, learn programming by Alice?

Tags: oop, 3d, alice, block-programming

Sorry I don't know is it the right place to post this question, if not please let me know.
I want to learn OOP and 3D game programming skill too, is Alice useful for old man too?
why it target on teen and child only?

Comment: Use whatever material you want to help you to learn to program. I suspect that they're using techniques (cartoons) designed to appeal to young kids, but if you can get past that and it's helpful, then why not? The thing that bothers me is that there should be a law against getting kids hooked on Java. :)

Comment: "there should be a law against getting kids hooked on Java" , Yeah, I agree!...Ha Ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a class in college that touched on alice, and from what I remember it was fairly basic and not really applicable to general programming. I wouldn't recommend trying to make a game with it. If you want to learn about 3D game programming I would suggest picking up a more widely used language. If you really are starting from scratch I would recommend looking into the Unity game engine (there is a free version) which allows you to program in C#, javascript, and boo.

Comment: Thanks Alex, your suggestion of Unity is good. I have google these several days and found Unity is popular on home made game industry today. I will take consider on it seriously. But in parallel, I will try the GameMaker too, anyway I agree with you the Unity use more "completed language" C#, I should consider it if language is matter.